# sed insert after first match

Tags: shell, sed

I am working with a .sh file that has the line

```
sed -i -e "/\[/r ${NEWPERMS}" ${CURRENTPERMS}
```

NEWPERMS and CURRENTPERMS are both files. This line has until recently inserted the contents of NEWPERMS after the [ in the CURRENTPERMS file. This has worked because until recently the CURRENTPERMS file has only had a single [. Suddenly, a second [ has appeared, and the above line is inserting after both.

I need it to continue only inserting after the FIRST instance of [. I have found dozens of answers online, none of which seem to work. I trued a "0," before the command, like seems to be the common answer, but it causes the file name of NEWPERMS to be inserted instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With GNU `sed`:

```
sed -i  "
    0,/\[/{
        /\[/r $NEWPERMS
    }" "$CURRENTPERMS"
```

Note that `0,/regexp/` address range is a GNU extension.

Comment: Thank you for replying! Trying this is giving me the following: sed: -e expression #1, char 0: unmatched `{'

Comment: Not sure if it matters, but $NEWPERMS and $OLDPERMS are both json files, which of course have many curly braces.

Comment: @JeffreyVanLaethem Make sure your sed is GNU sed and copy the command verbatim (embedded newlines are significant).

Comment: Ah, I had messed with the newlines. it works when copied as-is. Thanks!